# LMS throwing :sorry to interrupt error[invalid message context]

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service

I am trying to publish a message form lWC , but getting error as below:

```
lightning/messageService: invalid message context]
```

i have created the message channel file added it in the package.xml and deployed it to the org, below is my codes not sure any mistake i am making.
below is my code :

LMS MetaFile:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <fieldName>messageText</fieldName>
    <LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <masterLabel>SampleMessageChannel</masterLabel>
        <isExposed>true</isExposed>
        <lightningMessageFields>
            <description>Holds the message to display</description>
        </lightningMessageFields>
    </LightningMessageChannel>
```

LWC Code

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import messageChannel from '@salesforce/messageChannel/Sample__c';
import {publish, MessageContext} from 'lightning/messageService'
export default class Publisher extends LightningElement {
    @wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext;
    handleButtonClick() {
        let message = {messageText: 'This is a test'};
        publish(this.messageContext, messageChannel, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: A doubt, is the LMS metafile missing a `fieldName` or have you forgotten it to put it in code above? I see only `description`.

Second why are you importing `Sample__c` when you have deployed `SampleMessageChannel`

Comment: @NagendraSingh I think that is the answer!

Comment: sorry filed name is present at the top...

Comment: <fieldName>messageText</fieldName>

Comment: okay, but it is outside of the LightningMessageChannel

Answer (score 0):

The `fieldName` tag need to be inside the `LightningMessageChannel` tag. Like below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <fieldName>messageText</fieldName>
        <masterLabel>SampleMessageChannel</masterLabel>
        <isExposed>true</isExposed>
        <lightningMessageFields>
            <description>Holds the message to display</description>
        </lightningMessageFields>
    </LightningMessageChannel>
```

but there is still one more problem as stated by
@Nagendra Singh - the import needs to be for `SampleMessageChannel`

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import messageChannel from '@salesforce/messageChannel/SampleMessageChannel__c';
import {publish, MessageContext} from 'lightning/messageService'
export default class Publisher extends LightningElement {
    @wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext;
    handleButtonClick() {
        let message = {messageText: 'This is a test'};
        publish(this.messageContext, messageChannel, message);
    }
}
```